# Detecting user language and forwarding to proper lang folder

Tags: html, localization, detect

I have asked to make a URL look like:
site.com/en/public/index.html
There are /de/public and /ru/public folders. So on site.com I need to recognize user browser language and redirect him to his language version. (to make url look like www.site.com/en/public/index.html)

Structure looks like:

Root: en / de / ru / assets (folders that are in root folder on server)
inside each (en/de/ru) folder is /public folder which contains index.html.

How can I do it?

Comment: What kind of serverware and server-side languages do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

`window.navigator.userLanguage` is IE

`navigator.language` is FireFox and all other browsers

Now use the language var to your advantage.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language